# Unable to add row dynamically to Jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am performing 2 functions in jquery datatable.

1. To search and filter table dependent on select tags.
2. Adding rows dynamically to datatable via ajax.

As I add row, though row gets added to table and row count is increased in pagination but table displays null rows due to search function. As soon as I refresh the table I am able to see all the rows. I figured out that the main problem is in **$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push()** function due to which **table.rows.add($trHTML).draw();** is not working. Some dependency is getting created due to search function which I am unable to resolve. Please provide some suggestions to resolve it.

**Html**

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline  d-inline-flex mt-2 ml-2 align-items-start">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select id="cato"  class="form-control input-sm shadow-none" >
            <option disabled selected="true">-Category-</option>
            {% for i in ch %}
            <option value ="{{i.name}}">{{i.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        </div>      
        <div class="form-group">
           <select id="subo" class="form-control shadow-none">
            <option disabled selected="true">-Subcategory-</option>   
            </select>
        </div>  
          <!--Reset Button-->
          <button type="submit" onclick="resettable()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reset</button>    
    </form>
        
<button type="submit" id="bt" class="btn btn-success align-top m-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit" style="float:right !important"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add</button>  

        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modaledit" >
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title"><b>Add Product</b></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                    </div>
   
                <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #fffdd0;">
                    <!--Popup Form-->
                    <form id="form_post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Name" name="name" spellcheck="false" required autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <input type="text" id="desc" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description" name="desc" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Category</label>
                            <select id="catoo" class="form-control" name="category" required>
                                <option disabled selected="true">-Select Category-</option>
                                {% for i in ch %}
                                <option value ="{{i.name}}">{{i.name}}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Subcategory</label>
                            <select id="suboo" class="form-control" name="subcategory" required>
                                <option disabled selected="true">-Select Subcategory-</option>
                    
                            </select><br/>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="table-responsive" id="resp">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="example>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Subcategory</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="r">
                {% for i in pd %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{i.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.subcategory}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.category}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>

 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "bLengthChange": false,
  //searching: false,
  pageLength: 5,
  "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
  dom: 'tip',
  language : {
        "zeroRecords": " "             
    },
    "columnDefs": [{
    "defaultContent": "-",
    "targets": "_all"
  }]
});

table.column(0).visible(false);

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var filterCategory= $("#cato option:selected").text().toUpperCase();
    let filterSubCategory= $("#subo option:selected").text().toUpperCase();
    var subCategory = String(data[2]).toUpperCase();
    var category = String(data[3]).toUpperCase();
    if((filterSubCategory != "-SUBCATEGORY-")&&(filterSubCategory != "")) {
        console.log("2",filterSubCategory);
        if ( filterCategory == category && filterSubCategory == subCategory)
            {
            return true;
            }
        }
    else if(filterCategory != "-CATEGORY-") {
        console.log("1",filterCategory);
        if ( filterCategory == category)
            {
            return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
);

$('#cato').on('change', function() {
    $('#subo').val("");
  table.draw();
});

$('#subo').on('change', function() {
  table.draw();
});
       
$(document).on("submit","#form_post",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: "{% url 'getdetails1' %}",
                data:{
                    name:$('#name').val(),
                    desc:$('#desc').val(),
                    category:$("#catoo option:selected").text(),
                    subcategory:$("#suboo option:selected").text(),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    var trHTML='';
                    $("#form_post")[0].reset();
                    $('#modaledit').modal('hide');                
                    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data[0].i + '</td><td>' +data[0].n + '</td><td>' + data[0].s + '</td><td>' +data[0].c + '</td></tr>';                  
                    table.rows.add($(trHTML)).draw();
                    console.log(data);
                    table.rows.add([data[0].i,data[0].n,data[0].s,data[0].c]);
                    table.draw();
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: If you create a snippet of your problem it would really help us to help you.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Snipped wont work as I am fetching data from database which involves part of django too

Comment: You can easily simulate an ajax response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a little example with a little repository of mine, hoping it helps you solve your issue:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "bLengthChange": false,
  //searching: false,
  pageLength: 3,
  dom: 'tip'
});
  
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    
    var filterCategory= $("#cato option:selected").text().toUpperCase();
    var filterSubCategory= $("#subo option:selected").text().toUpperCase();
    var subCategory = String(data[2]).toUpperCase();
    var category = String(data[3]).toUpperCase();
    
    //console.log(filterSubCategory);
    
    if(filterSubCategory != "-SELECT SUBCATEGORY-") {
        if ( filterCategory == category && filterSubCategory == subCategory)
             return true;
        }
        else if(filterCategory != "-SELECT CATEGORY-") {
            if ( filterCategory == category)
             return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
);

$('#cato').on('change', function() {
  $('#subo').val("");
  table.draw();
});

$('#subo').on('change', function() {
  table.draw();
});

function getInfo() {

        var $subCategory = $("#subo option:selected").text()

        $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url: "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/SagnalracSO/repo/items?subcategory=" + $subCategory,
      /*data:{
        name:$('#name').val(),
        desc:$('#desc').val(),
        category:$("#catoo option:selected").text(),
        ,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
      },*/
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
      
          if($subCategory.toUpperCase() == '-SELECT SUBCATEGORY-') {
              alert('Select a SubCategory');
                jqXHR.abort();
          }
      },
      success: function(data) {
        
        var item = data[0];
        var jRow = $("<tr>").append("<td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.product + "</td><td>" + item.subcategory + "</td><td>" + item.category + "</td>").append("</tr>");
        table.row.add(jRow).draw();

      }
   });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<select id="cato" class="form-control" >
  <option value="" disabled selected="true">-Select Category-</option>
  <option>Electronics</option>
  <option>Sports</option>
</select>

<select id="subo" class="form-control">
   <option value="" disabled selected="true">-Select Subcategory-</option>
   <option>Laptop</option>
   <option>Mobile</option>
</select>

<table id="example" class="table display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Subcategory</th>
      <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="r">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Samsung</td>
      <td>Mobile</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Racket</td>
      <td>Tennis</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Bat</td>
      <td>Cricket</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Dell</td>
      <td>Laptop</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Iphone</td>
      <td>Mobile</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Soccer Ball</td>
      <td>Soccer</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="ADD ROWS" onClick="getInfo()" />
```

If your Ajax request returns more than one record, then you can replace this:

```
var item = data[0];
    var jRow = $("<tr>").append("<td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.product + "</td><td>" + item.subcategory + "</td><td>" + item.category + "</td>").append("</tr>");
    table.row.add(jRow).draw();
```

with this:

```
for (var item in data) {
    
        var item = data[item];
        
        var jRow = $("<tr>").append("<td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.product + "</td><td>" + item.subcategory + "</td><td>" + item.category + "</td>").append("</tr>");
        table.row.add(jRow).draw();
    }
```

By the way, if in the future you want to create examples that involve calling an API (via Ajax request), just as I did in this example, I'd like to recommend you this website **[JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)**

Comment: Thank you once again for your reply. Your code is perfect but the submit function where you used the getinfo() function actually fetches the form data which you have commented /*data*/ part.. I am sending the data to the server and recieving value via ajax. You see in my example,I have used form_post which posts the form value on submit in html and in jquery I am fetching all the fields. Now my form values are not getting received and the page is getting reloaded as e.preventdefault() is removed

Comment: @Karthik: Yes, I know. I had to comment the **data** part of your Ajax request, because in the website I'm using for getting data online for examples like this, I still don't know how to perform a **POST** request, only **GET**. By the way, I have one question. Is it necessary to perform a submit action in order to get your data? Because if you're using Ajax you can fetch it in other ways, just as I did in my example.

Comment: I am fetching data using ajax only, the way you used. The thing is that both the form and table are in the same page hence such a mess is getting created. But the thing is that as suggested by you, it worked with GET only, I was trying to send form data to django view via POST but due to multiple actions its not working, so GET is only recommended in this case. Just a doubt that, whole page is getting reloaded on button click. How to avoid that here, in my above example I avoided it by using preventdefault()

Comment: @Karthik: In this line `<button type="submit" onclick="resettable()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reset</button>` replace `type="submit"`with `type="button"`. About the type of request, I'm sure it's possible to perform a POST request.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr life saver. It worked as expected now. Only the thing is that the page is getting reloaded instead of table on button click. Will figure it out soon. Thanks for JSONPlaceholder I will refer this from now onwards